# WPF control should break out of parent's clipping box

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am looking for a way to break out of the parent control's clipping box in WPF. Like for example:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <!-- This control should overlay the parent (the grid) - is there a way to do this? -->
  <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Width="400" />
</Grid>
```

As in the example, I want to add a control to the Visual Tree and it should overlay the parent control. I played around with ClipToBounds and the ZIndex, but they seemed to have no influence. The Rectangle was always clipped to the Grid's column.

Is this possible at all with WPF or do I have to add it somewhere else in the Visual Tree?

Thanks,

Comment: Set `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` on the Ractangle.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the example was too specific. I need to break out of the parent's clipping box in a way that would also work for other parent controls.

Comment: Put the Rectangle and the Grid (or any other Panel) on top of each other in an outer Grid.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do in WPF.  Practically anything you can think of in terms of UI can be done in WPF and if you doubt it I except the challenge.  Knowing the mechanics of WPF is quite different; however, to be fair, I believe it's the best logic for a UI design pattern by leaps and bounds compared to anything else we have to work with.  So, that said, there are quite a few ways to get what you want accomplished... The easiest answer may be to just place the Rectangle outside of the Grid altogether.  If you provide more XAML and an image of what you want we can give options and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:
[image]

Is produced by the following xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Width="400" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FFBD3A3A" />
    <!-- This control overlays the parent control -->
    <Canvas Background="Blue" Width="55" Height="55" Grid.Column="1" Margin="226,124,37,140"></Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I would advise not using this approach and laying your controls out differently but the canvas control is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That was really what I was looking for :-)